# Add value in Javascript after another input

Tags: javascript

How to automatically Add value +1 after keyup?

```
<input id="tahun1" name="tahun1" type="number"> 
<input id="tahun2" name="tahun2" type="number" readonly>

<script>
$("#tahun1").keyup(function(){
$("#tahun2").val(this.value);});
</script>
```

for example if I insert "2015" in "tahun1" then in "tahun2" should be "2016" automatically

thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1):

Parse the value using `Number()` or `parseInt()` then increment the value and update the input field.

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="tahun1" name="tahun1" type="number">
<input id="tahun2" name="tahun2" type="number" readonly>

<script>
  $("#tahun1").keyup(function() {
    $("#tahun2").val(Number(this.value) + 1);
  });
</script>
```

Comment: @afhamz : glad to help :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```js
$("#tahun1").keyup(function(){
  
    $("#tahun2").val(parseInt($(this).val())+1);
  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="tahun1" name="tahun1" type="number"> 
<input id="tahun2" name="tahun2" type="number" readonly>
```